# Calculating sum of a discrete signal (explain summation)

Tags: summation, signal-processing

I have to find a convolution of two signals

$h[n] = 0.5^nu[n]$

$x[n] = u[n]-u[n-3]$

the final sum, which is correct is:

$$\sum_{m=n-2}^n 0.5^mu[m] $$

note that i replaced $n-k$ with $m$, that is
$ m = n-k $

So, in regards to parameter $n$, I have to decypher the formula.
The result is:

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
0, & n < 0 \\
2 \cdot (1-0.5^{n} \cdot 0.5), & 0 \le n \lt 2 \\
1.75 \cdot 0.5^{n} / 0.5^{2}, & n \ge 2
\end{array}
$$

But, i don't know how to get those results. Can you please explain?

The results are correct (maybe i just typed something wrong, if that's the case, I'm sorry in advance)

I'm having trouble with the sums, so I'm guessing this is more appropriate for the math.stackexchange than dsp.stackexchange.

Comment: Is $u(n)$ the unit step funtion?

Comment: What formula are you trying to decipher? Before you do any computation, if you look at the problem and picture what it is that a convolution does, you will see that it is simply a three-point running average of $h[n]$ (assuming that $u[n]$ is meant to be the step-function). You should be able to work out the solution from that observation alone.

Comment: Cross-post. Please see my answer [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9802/calculating-sum-of-a-discrete-signal/9803#9803).